# VS template parameters: Get partial project name

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I have a multi-project solution template.
I've created it using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-template) guide.

My solution is generating multi-platform projects with a central shared project:

- `MyProject.Shared`
- `MyProject.UWP`
- `MyProject.Droid`
- etc.

The problem is that when I use `$safeprojectname$.Shared` in the *csproj* file of the individual projects (let's say in the UWP one) in order to add a reference to the shared project, what gets generated is `MyProject1.UWP.Shared` instead of `MyProject1.Shared`.

How do I refer to the shared project name / solution name from the individual projects?

P.S. There is the [`$SpecificSolutionName$`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2017#reserved-template-parameters) parameter, but that only works if the user checked the *Create solution directory* option, not good enough for me.

TL;DR

How do I get partial project name from parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ext_safeprojectname$` does the trick.

([credit](https://github.com/nventive/Uno/blob/master/src/SolutionTemplate/UnoLibraryTemplate/CrossTargetedLibrary.vstemplate#L19))

Answer (score 1):

In the root *.vstemplate* file you should use `ProjectName="$projectname$"` in `ProjectTemplateLink` tag:

```xml
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Shared" CopyParameters="true">
        MyProject.Shared\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.UWP" CopyParameters="true">
        MyProject.UWP\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Droid" CopyParameters="true">
        MyProject.Droid\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
```